# How can I prevent Wordpress to wrap <br> into a <p> paragragraph

Tags: formatting, html-editor

When I create a new page and put `<br class="clear">` into the HTML view it gets rendered as

```
<p>
  <br class="clear">
</p>
```

This causes problems with the theme `http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/?theme=Lotus` where the `<br>` is not wrapped.

How can remove the wrapping?

Comment: There's already a few solutions to this problem [in this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/stop-wordpress-wrapping-images-in-a-p-tag).

Comment: Does using `<div class="clear"></div>` solve the problem? I think using a div will work around the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)  instead of `<br class="clear">`

Comment: Thanks, is there a particular shortcode you had in mind? Or do you mean I should create my own shortcode with <br class="clear"> as content?

Comment: @Civic, I mean create your own. Another solution is to [filter the content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) It's even more easier.

Answer (score 0):

you can strip all the filters by calling [`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) instead of [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content)