# Stripping <p> tag from elements in post

Tags: posts, editor, content, the-content

I'm fine with `P` tags for most of the content, since it makes styling easier. However I'd like to have `span` `div` `iframe` and possibly other HTML tags to not be placed inside of a `p` for post.

I saw [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/stop-wordpress-wrapping-images-in-a-p-tag?rq=1) but it doesn't quite solve it. Also, I saw the [linked CSSTricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-paragraph-tags-from-around-images/), and tried a sample code that used iFrame on it for my `spans`. Am I doing something wrong with the code? Or what should I do to remove the `p` tags from html tags in my post.

Here's my code that isn't working:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<span .*>*.<\/span>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
} add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you would like to apply the `the_content` filter to remove all `span`, `div` and `iframe` tags that reside inside a `p`-element?

Answer (score 0):

To me you code looks good, I would recommend adding priority as high as 9999
Heres how :

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images', '9999');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Open your `functions.php` file and add the following PHP snippet

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```